# Get RGB components from background color

Tags: javascript, css

Assuming the element's background color can be set in many ways, like `fuchsia`, `#BED`, `rgb(213, 32, 98)`, `hsl(120,60%,70%)` is there a way to retrieve RGB components that browser uses to render?

I do not mean brute-force parsing of any possible string, but rather a way to read the browser calculated data which must be stored somewhere before sending them to the rendering engine.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle ?

Comment: the comment of enhzflep almost answers the question, the remaining piece of validity is if the returned value (rgb notation in my case) is always the format used for *resolved value* mentioned in the note No. 3 in the link